# How can I keep Windows 8 from mounting flash drives as local disks?

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive

New flash drives that are Windows 8 compatible will mount the devices as local disks when inserted. I need for them to be seen as "removable". My older USB sticks work fine but I need bigger sizes now. Does anyone know of a way to keep Windows 8 from doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Does [USB Safely Remove](http://safelyremove.com/index.htm) help? One of it's features is **Lets you prevent Windows from assigning specified drive letters to hot-plug devices**. It has a full featured 30 day trial ...

Comment: @DavidPostill No unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: there are drivers/tools which flip the removable bit of USB drives. look if they can set it again. http://scsi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877#2166593

Comment: The only tool I've seen is for Lexar Flash Drives. And I've heard they don't work on their newer devices. I was instead looking for a way to keep "Windows" from "telling me" what I want to do with my drives.

Comment: Questions: In what format is the flash drive formatted (NTFS, FAT32)? Are you using a generic Windows driver or have you installed a driver furnished with the stick? Which make is the stick? Some manufacturers, like Sandisk, manufactured such drives during 2013 to comply with Windows 8 new guidelines, but have stopped doing that in 2014. So replacing the drive by a newer (or older) may solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually Windows 8 doing this, but the USB drive itself, SanDisk and a few other manufacturers set them up to be seen as local fixed disk for windows 8 certification in 2012.  SanDisk has reversed that decision now.

The only real way to change it would be either to go out and buy a new usb flash drive from a manufacturer that didn't implement this or try to use the tool that @magicandre1981 linked in his comment.